# Lorentz transformation of energy-momentum tensor of electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, inertial-frames, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, poynting-vector

I wanted to calculate the power density of a moving antenna; it needs the Poynting vector, which is a part of the energy-momentum tensor of electromagnetic fields. My question is whether this tensor satisfies the principle of relativity to be transformed between frames?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the energy-momentum tensor transforms the same as any other rank-2 tensor in relativity.